# How can performance increase when using multiple nodes in MPI, when ratio between processes and problem size is fixed?

Tags: mpi

I have implemented Game of Life on MPI. I get expected speed up values, unless i use mutliple nodes.

I ran it on computer which has 20 cores per node. As seen in the graph, which is in the link, when going from 20 to 25 cores and increasing the problemsize accordingly, it performes better than expected. Then start to go linearly from there again. How can this be ?[Plot of weak scaling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Os9Uc.png)

Comment: Do you mean that you went from running your program on 20 cores on one node, to running it on 25 cores across 2 nodes ?

Comment: Yes that is exaclty what i ment!

Comment: We need to see code ([mcve]) and specific performance measurements in order to properly help here rather than guessing...

Comment: you need to understand how your application behaves. if it is memory bound (e.g. the memory bandwidth limits the performance), then you have twice the memory bandwidth when running on 25 cores (2 nodes) vs 20 cores (1 node). You also need to understand the ratio computation vs communication to understand which benefits can be expected when running on multiple nodes.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. Investigated the ratio between computation and communication. The computaional time was was the one causing the offset. I think it should be because of the amount of availeble shared cache in the node. When spread across two nodes, more of the matrices can be stored in cache.